# Crontab /bin/sh syntax

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I was not able to find the answer for this myself.

As cron uses /bin/sh, im getting Syntax error's.
I have a cron job, which uses the following command in it

`2,17,32,47 * * * * tar -czvf /opt/SOMEFILES /var/lib/$(date +"%Y/%m/%d")`

OR

`2,17,32,47 * * * * tar -czvf /opt/$(date +"%Y/%m/%d")/somefiles /var/lib/$(date +"%Y/%m/%d")`

Basically, this is just an example, the real cron job is a little different. Tried to give some type of an example.

`$(date +"%Y/%m/%d")` This is the part i am not sure how to use in Cron.

How could i use it in cron?  the curdate could even be a folder where it goes.

Comment: @muru as i mentioned in my question, i had no idea how to google this perfectly.

Comment: So I googled it for you.

Comment: @muru well thankyou, but i forgot to add another way i have to use my cron. As a folder indicator. As the link you posted does not say.

Comment: I don't see how it makes any difference what the output of `date` is used as.

Comment: Aight, i took a closer look, tested and noticed i had my own type error. Thanks for this google search. Gave me what i needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have the exact errors you are getting, but my guess would be this is an escaped characters issue (you are using forward slashes rather than back slashes for date)

> The "sixth" field (the rest of the line) specifies the command to be run. The entire command portion of the line, up to a newline or % character, will be executed by /bin/sh or by the shell specified in the SHELL variable of the cronfile. Percent-signs (%) in the command, unless escaped with backslash (), will be changed into newline charac- ters, and all data after the first % will be sent to the command as standard input.

Try more like this format

```
`date +\%Y\%m\%d\`
```

Comment: The thing is, i also need to use this as a folder field. I have a program that generates data and makes folders as `2018/04/05` and sometimes i have to move inside the `curdate` folder, so i cant use   `\ `

Comment: Nvm, thanks. this also helped. Just my bad understanding was the reason i failed to get it working at first.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1:** Put backslash `\` with `date`

```
2,17,32,47 * * * * tar -czvf /opt/SOMEFILES >> /var/lib/`date +\%Y\%m\%d\`
```

**Solution 2:**

You can also put your commands into a shell file and then execute the shell file with cron.

**jobs.sh**

```
 tar -czvf /opt/SOMEFILES >> /var/lib/`date +\%Y\%m\%d\`
```

**cron**

```
2,17,32,47 * * * * jobs.sh
```

Comment: I'v edited my comment as i forgot to mention that i have to use it also with folder indicator.

Comment: A bare `%` in the command field is interpreted by cron as separatring the command and input, so this is incorrect.

Comment: The `jobs.sh` file now uses the escaping needed for cron, which is unnecessary for sh, and forgets command substitution.

Comment: @muru now I edited my answer.